# Resetting setInterval on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, jquery-click-event

**Updated with latest code:**

Here is the latest code, still has 2 buttons and 2 functions.  Each button should run the relievant function and set the code to run the same button after every minute via the setInterval.  For some reason, the very first setInterval always seems to stay set, even after clicking the second button which should change it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myTimer = null;

    get_popular();

    clearInterval(myTimer);
    myTimer = null;
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {$('a.btnPopular').click();}, 60*1000);

    $('a.btnPopular').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        get_popular( $(this) );

        clearInterval(myTimer);
        myTimer = null;
        myTimer = setInterval(function() {$('a.btnPopular').click();}, 60*1000);
    });

    function get_popular( that ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_popular.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // error message here
            },
            success: function(results) { 
                if ( typeof that != "undefined" ) {
                    that.closest('.outer_div').find('.inner_div').empty().append( results );
                } else {
                    $('.inner_div.new').empty().append( results ).removeClass('new');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $('a.btnLatest').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        get_latest( $(this) );

        clearInterval(myTimer);
        myTimer = null;
        myTimer = setInterval(function() {$('a.btnLatest').click();}, 60*1000);
    });

    function get_latest( that ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_latest.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // error message here
            },
            success: function(results) { 
                if ( typeof that != "undefined" ) {
                    that.closest('.outer_div').find('.inner_div').empty().append( results );
                } else {
                    $('.inner_div.new').empty().append( results ).removeClass('new');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
setInterval(function() {$('a.btnPopular').click();}, 60*1000);
```

Edit:
Also you can't call `get_popular();` without a parameter ;)

Edit 2:
This should solve your problems:

```
var myTimer = null;

$('a.btnPopular').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    get_popular($(this));
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){$('a.btnPopular').click();}, 60*1000);
});

$('a.btnLatest').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    get_latest($(this));
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){$('a.btnLatest').click();}, 60*1000);
});
```

Comment: Or: `setInterval("$('s.btnPopular').click()", 60*1000)`

Comment: @MihaRekar, I've just tried this and it's an improvement.  But if I click on the second button, the correct stuff happens, but the timer continues to execute the click event of the first button.  Why are the timers not switching?

Comment: That is because the first interval is still running, you have to clear it. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590671/how-to-do-a-clear-interval-in-javascript

Comment: @MihaRekar, I've tried clearing it, but it's still giving me the same problem.  I have updated the original question with the latest code.  I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: I've just noticed that it is working in IE8, but not in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {$('a.btnPopular').trigger('click');}, 60*1000);
// Ad do this
$(elem).click(function(){}) => $(elem).on('click', function(){});
```

Comment: It's not really worth replacing click(), as in the jQuery converts all the 'shortcut' event handlers (like click()) to on("event", fn) anyway.